# Making target argument mandatory with docker multi-stage build?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

We're containerising our build pipeline with docker in a CI environment. We have a setup with [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), with the included (simplified) Dockerfile. The idea is to, depending on the trigger (branch type), run `docker build` with the relevant `--target` argument. For example, deploy phase should only happen when the merge to master trigger occurs.

We invoke the build with docker with the following command: `docker build --target build-phase`. However, to avoid that the later phases are accidentally executed, how can change the dockerfile to make the `target` argument mandatory?

```
FROM node:10.16 as build-phase
WORKDIR /app/
COPY . /app
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build


### UNIT TEST PHASE ###
FROM build-phase as unit-test-phase

# Install java for firebase emulator
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

# Run tests
RUN npm run ci-test

### INTEGRATION TEST PHASE ###
FROM unit-test-phase as int-test-phase
RUN npm run ci-int-test

### DEPLOY PHASE ###
FROM int-test-phase as deploy-phase
RUN ./deploy.sh
```

Comment: I'd run all of the stages after "build" outside of Docker.  (Integration tests here are a problem because you can't make cross-container calls from a Dockerfile, and none of the later stages create an artifact you'd want to persist in a runnable Docker image.)

Comment: I see. Then I guess the question is where you would run the stages after build phase? The neat thing about the current setup is that with the Dockerfile, docker creates a deterministic environment with both java+node.